# Retrieving information from custom dialog called from within non-Activity class

Tags: android, dialog

I am working on a board game app (similar to chess). I have the activity GameBoardActivity which listens for clicks on a GridView, and at each click calls functions from a class Game to handle what should occur.

Within the class Game is the data about where pieces are and the method `Move(int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo)` where piece movement is handled.

For certain movements that a user may specify (e.g. that the piece at xFrom, yFrom should go to xTo, yTo) I want to provide them with a choice between two options. You can imagine that one choice is to go there normally, and the other is to go there as a transformed piece. To do this I want to display a custom dialog that presents the two choices for the user to click.

My custom Dialog class is given below:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{

Context mcontext;
Button button1;
Button button2;
int choice;    //holds value of user's choice


public CustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mcontext = context;
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    choice = 0; //no choice yet 
}

public void setLayout(){

    this.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
         choice = 1;
         break;
    case R.id.button2:
         choice = 2;
         break;
    }   
    dismiss();
}
}
```

What I'm not clear on is how to pass the information about the user's choice back to the class Game.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to parent Activity via the constructor of the dialog:

```
private final MyActivity mCaller;

public CustomDialog(MyActivity caller) {
    super(caller);
    mCaller = caller;

    //.......
}
```

Pass values to calling activity by invoking its methods:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
         mCaller.setChoice(1);
         break;
    case R.id.button2:
         mCaller.setChoice(2);
         break;
    }   
    dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this suggestion (using a reference to Game, not the Activity, since the dialog is created from the class Game which is referenced by the Activity) but the line where I set the onClickListener for the buttons is giving me a null pointer exception. I can't figure out why ... any ideas?

Comment: @Rookatu You'll need reference to an Activity object, not any other object.

Comment: Hey user117. I fixed that null pointer exception (was a matter of initiating the buttons before calling setContentView, in case anyone wonders) and your idea seems to have worked despite referencing only the Game object and not the activity. Why should it be an Activity instead? Also, should I worry about memory getting eaten up by referencing these large objects, or will the garbage collector take care of that when the Dialog closes?

Comment: @Rookatu Actually you need a `Context` subclass in constructor, looks like you `Game` object also has a context. That's fine :).

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean class for storing the button actions ....
While clicking the events store it in a bean 
In a game class u access the action values for button from the bean class